# Check for response status without Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alamofire, fetch

I followed a tutorial to how fetch something from Firebase. The guy in the video said you maybe should check for the response status of 200 (HTTP OK).
What are the benefits from checking this and is there a way without Alamofire?

Code looks like this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl) else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
    if let err = err { print("Failed to fetch the profile image:", err); return }

    //check for response status here

    guard let data = data else { return }
    let image = UIImage(data: data)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.profileImage.image = image
    }

    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most APIs we use have their own sets of status code returned when requesting the content. For simple use like your example it should be sufficient to not make use of it, but in large applications the code has their meanings and the client should handle them properly. There are many resources from which you can read about the advantages of status codes.

You can check the status code from URLSession Task like so:

```
guard let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl) else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
  if let err = err { print("Failed to fetch the profile image:", err); return }

   //check for response status here
   if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
    }

  guard let data = data else { return }
  let image = UIImage(data: data)

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.profileImage.image = image
  }

  }.resume()
}
```

Since `HTTPURLResponse` is subclass of `URLResponse` and is responsible for accessing info about HTTP load you could easily cast the response and get the `statusCode`

Comment: Exactly what I searched for! Thank you